# Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer

Tags: ios, xamarin, package

I am trying run my working project in another pc gives me this types of errors.

> Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content

I tried some of the solutions that I found on the internet, but they didn't help me.

=> deleted zip file and downloaded again.

=> deleted bin and obj folder and restarted VS

=> clean, rebuild, run

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons you're having this issue:

1: Check that you've android sdk on this PC and also check that your project's sdk is properly referenced from your solution.

2: Go to project nuget packages in solution explorer and see all the android related nuget packages are installed in your project.

[image: Nuget Packages in solution explorer]